# Ajax request that depends on data from another request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to nest an ajax request inside of another (with .then) so i can use the data of the first one on the second ajax request. In this case i want to use the coordinates of the first ajax call to the second ajax request (map coordinates).
The variables are latt and long.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#submitWeather').click(function(){           
       var city= $("#city").val();
       var latt, long;             
        if(city !=''){                
          $.ajax({                   
               url:'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + city + "&units=metric" + "&APPID="....",
               type: "GET",
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function(data){
                   console.log(data);                    
                   var widget = show(data);
                   $("#show").html(widget);                   
                   latt = coord.lat;
                   long = coord.lon;                       
               }

           }).then($.ajax({

              url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="..."&callback=initMap', 
               type: "GET",
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function initMap() {
               var uluru = {lat: +latt+, lng: +long+};
               var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
               zoom: 4,
               center: uluru
            });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }         
    });
  }else{                
      $("#error").html("<div class='alert alert-danger text-center'> The field cannot be empty, please enter a city! </div>");
  }
});
});
```

Comment: Just put the second function inside the success function of the first.

Comment: [JavaScript Promises: an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap the second ajax call into a function and call it after success of the first call.

```
    function secondajaxcall(latt, long){
    /** your second ajax call **/

    }
    function firstajaxcall(){
     $.ajax({

             XXXXXXXX,

               success: function(data){
                   latt = data.lat;
                   long = data.long;
                   secondajaxcall(latt, long); /* CALL SECOND FUNCTION **/ 
               }

           })


    }
    firstajaxcall();
```

Comment: yes, this is no copy and paste code. It will not work out of the box. Just pass your variables to a second ajax function.